Arctic polar vortex collapse
What if the Arctic vortex collapses (not forming during cold months) due to anthropogenic global warming and the warming of the Arctic Ocean?
If it "dies" in the coming decades, is it likely that colder and snowier winters of preindustrial era (for several decades, until the Ocean will warm enough) will return to a significant part of Europe?
Arctic winds should "brake the defence" of the polar jet stream and more likely to be dominant in Europe in the peak of the season
